# Changing UITextField with UIPickerView, not calling EditingDidChange Action

Tags: ios, objective-c

Having a slight problem here.

The (IBAction) method I have set up for UITextfields EditingDidChange is not being called when the textField is changed when using a UIPickerView as input.

However, it works fine when using keyboard input.

Does the UIPickerView not send out its current selection until it's dismissed or something?

An alternative is to probably use the UIPickerView method, didSelectRow to perform the updates I'm after.

Is there there a unique way I'm unaware of that will get this to work how I want?

Comment: Why not use a UITextFieldDelegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have something like this to setup your text field:

```
    self.citys = @[@"Buenos Aires", @"Bahia Blanca", @"Azul",@"Pigue"];
    self.namePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    self.namePicker.delegate = self;
    self.namePicker.dataSource = self;
    self.namePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    self.accessoryView = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(onNameSelection)];
    [self.accessoryView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:doneButton]];

    self.textField.inputView = self.namePicker;
    self.textField.inputAccessoryView = self.accessoryView;
```

And something like this to set the text when the user finish the selection:

```
- (void) onNameSelection{
    NSInteger row = [self.namePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];

    self.textField.text = [self.citys objectAtIndex:row];
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

So... You don't need the action EditingChanged, because you know when the `textfield.text`  is changed.

Maybe you also have something like this to change the text while the user select row in the picker:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    self.textField.text = [self.citys objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Again, you know when the `textfield.text` is changed.

So... Because **YOU** are the responsible of the changes on the `textfield.text` **YOU** are the responsible of call the function associated to the EditingChanged action.

Comment: I ended up using didSelectRow. Are you able to explain the reason why the editingDidChange method isn't called when using a pickerView as input?

Comment: Are you changing the text like I said you? So, you are changing the text programatically, and you are the resposible to triger the event.

Comment: When a new row is selected in the pickerView, the content inside a textField is getting changed. I'm just curious how doing this doesn't call the `editingDidChange` method on the textField. Just like it would with keyboard input. You answer did solve my problem though. Thankyou.